# select a value from kendo-dropdownlist using Selenium WebDriver(Java) for which the element is seen in the Inspect Element tab only when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code: Dropdown - Before Selecting any value

```
<kendo-dropdownlist _ngcontent-c25="" class="wh-kendo-form-control k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-touched ng-dirty ng-invalid" formcontrolname="ProgramType" ngdefaultcontrol="" css="1">
        <span role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" dir="ltr" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dc9964bd-c71b-44f9-be3f-fc373c4f149f" aria-activedescendant="43ae0146-4b8a-41fb-ba3c-528d3aa53a42-0">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-input" style="">
               <!---->
               <!---->Select One</span>
           <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
               <span class="k-i-arrow-s k-icon"></span>
           </span>
           <!---->
        </span>
        <!---->
        <!---->
  </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

HTML Code: Dropdown - when selected "Client Incentive"

```
<kendo-dropdownlist _ngcontent-c25="" class="wh-kendo-form-control k-widget k-dropdown k-header ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" formcontrolname="ProgramType" ngdefaultcontrol="" css="1">
        <span role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" dir="ltr" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dc9964bd-c71b-44f9-be3f-fc373c4f149f" aria-activedescendant="43ae0146-4b8a-41fb-ba3c-528d3aa53a42-192">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-input" style="">
               <!---->
               <!---->Client Incentive</span>
           <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
               <span class="k-i-arrow-s k-icon"></span>
           </span>
           <!---->
        </span>
        <!---->
        <!---->
  </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: Could someone please provide script to select a value using Selenium Webdriver for the above

Comment: IMO, the dropdown is not from this HTML perhaps somewhere else within the DOM.

Comment: Inspecting the dropdown shows the same code highlighted in the Elements tab

Comment: WebElement pt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@unselectable='on'][text()='Select One']");
Select elm = new Select(pt);
elm.selectByVisibleText("Client Incentive"); -- This gives an error "element should have been select but was span in selenium webdriver" @DebanjanB

Comment: Actions actn=new Actions(driver);  
actn.moveToElement(pt).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
WebElement toselect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@unselectable='on'][text()='Client Incentive']");  
actn.moveToElement(toselect).click().build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
It worked for me. Just passed in the id of the element and the default text you which to select. You can always modify it for your liking.

```
public void ResetKendoDropdown(string identifier, string defaultText) {
    var kendoElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Id(identifier));
    kendoElement.Click();

    var currentItem = kendoElement.FindElement(By.ClassName("k-dropdown-wrap"));
    while (currentItem.Text != defaultText) {
        currentItem.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowUp);
    }

    kendoElement.Click();
}
```